# Run computer as root without terminal

Tags: permissions, root, gui

I have a lamp project and I can't move my project in the file I'm supposed to move unless I do it from terminal as root, and then it doesn't let me open the project and change it, I have a lots of files I have to change and it's very time consuming to open them all from terminal each time I want to change them. How can I run my computer as root without the terminal?( I am new to ubuntu )

Comment: @muru Does opening nautilus as root let us to edit files (in gedit for example) as root as well?

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha it should, the process is running as root, anything it opens should also be running as root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Do *not* run as `root`

While you could simply activate the password for the `root` user (with `passwd`), **do not do that.** It's a very bad practice from a security point of view. Instead, you should handle permissions properly.

## Run a file manager as root

You can start Nautilus with `sudo` privileges in the usual way:

```
sudo nautilus
```

Then you can copy the files that you need to move (I assume under `/var/www`). You can also open a file in a text editor, but keep in mind that the editor is going to run with elevated privileges as well. Do not run untrusted programs in this setting.

When you are done moving the files, you'll probably want to recursively fix the owner to `www-data` and its group:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/*
```